# overlapping variable doesn't change variable

Tags: python, variables

I can't even explain. Here is my code

```
foods = {12345670 : 'orange(s)',
     87654325 : 'pineapple(s)'}
loop = 10
while loop == 10:
    full_list = input("Type: ")
    if full_list == 'end':
        break
    amount = int(input("Amount: "))
    subtotal = 0
    item = int(full_list)
    if item in foods:
        print("That would be {} {}".format(amount, foods[item]))
        if full_list == '12345670':
            price = (0.50 * amount)
            print("Added Orange(s)")
            print("Added "+str(price))
            subtotal = subtotal + price
        if full_list == '87654325':
            price = (1.00 * amount)
            subtotal = subtotal + price
            print("Added Pineapple(s)")
            print("Added "+str(price))
print("Your subtotal is " +str(subtotal))
```

I'm trying to get my subtotal to change accordingly to what the user purchases, I haven't finished making my list of purchasable items and so I don't want to change the name of the variable every time. What is the problem here? Why doesn't the variable `subtotal` change?

Comment: The subtotal does change, but you initialize it to 0 at the beginning of each loop. Just set it to 0 before the loop starts.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks that helped so much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foods = {12345670 : 'orange(s)',
     87654325 : 'pineapple(s)'}
loop = 10
subtotal = 0             # <------ moved it outside of the while loop
while loop == 10:
    full_list = input("Type: ")
    if full_list == 'end':
        break
    amount = int(input("Amount: "))
    item = int(full_list)
    if item in foods:
        print("That would be {} {}".format(amount, foods[item]))
        if full_list == '12345670':
            price = (0.50 * amount)
            print("Added Orange(s)")
            print("Added "+str(price))
            subtotal = subtotal + price
        if full_list == '87654325':   #should be an elif not an if
            price = (1.00 * amount)
            subtotal = subtotal + price
            print("Added Pineapple(s)")
            print("Added "+str(price))
print("Your subtotal is " +str(subtotal))
```

Every time you looped you restarted the total cost to 0 and it only kept the latest price. Move it outside of the while loop where I commented and you should be fine. Also use `elif` if you want to chain similar `if` statements together.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following

```
if full_list == '12345670'
```

But it will never enter this if statement because your input type is an integer not a string. Do this without the single quotes instead:

```
if full_list == 12345670
```

Comment: in Python 3.x (which I'm assuming it is) input always returns a `str` based on a few factors, the print statement, and also `full_list = input("Type: ")` would  throw errors if you typed `end` as it would try to `eval('end')`

Comment: But then it won't do the things underneath -_-

Comment: Look at @MooingRawr solution.